# How to do MEMCACHE in WAMP server WINDOWS XP

Tags: php, wamp

Iam running WAMP server and just enabled php_memcache extension and have tried the code

```
<?php

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

$version = $memcache->getVersion();
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";

$tmp_object = new stdClass;
$tmp_object->str_attr = 'test';
$tmp_object->int_attr = 123;

$memcache->set('key', $tmp_object, false, 10) or die ("Failed to save data at the server");
echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds)<br/>\n";

$get_result = $memcache->get('key');
echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";

var_dump($get_result);

?>
```

and i got the following error

```
Notice: Memcache::connect() [memcache.connect]: Server localhost (tcp 11211) failed with: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060) in C:\wamp\www\memcache\test1.php on line 4

Warning: Memcache::connect() [memcache.connect]: Can't connect to localhost:11211, A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060) in C:\wamp\www\memcache\test1.php on line 4
Could not connect
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you just don't need memcache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memcache extension, on the PHP side of things, provides function so PHP can connect to a memcached server.

But you have to :

- install such a server *(or several or them, as memcached works as a cluster of servers)*
- start it
- configure it : mainly, indicate

  - how much memory it can use,
  - on each port it listens to connections

Here, **are you sure that you installed a memcached server** on your local machine ?

Comment: If he didn't then the program should die with "Could not connect",is that right? :)

Comment: It did die with *Could not connect*, did it not ? *(see the last line of the error, after the notice and the warning)*

Comment: ...Oh,you're right.I met this problem before and I solved it as my answer said.Just a little curious he didn't pick my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you're using WAMP you need to add this line to your php.ini file. (mine was in: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\php.ini)

```
extension=php_memcache.dll
```

---

If you are running 64 bit WAMP:

The common service and extensions will not work for you.

Install the 64 bit memcached service:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.northscale.com/memcached-win64-1.4.4-14.zip

And one of these php extensions (to match your php version):

Php 5.3: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?o60feet9sw71six

Php 5.4: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?8d3vd26z3fg6bf1

Comment: In december 2013, this post is the only one that is working for Windows 8 with the current release of Wamp. Thank you @Beachhouse

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your connecting codes as follows

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a brill guide I have just followed

[Installing Memcached for PHP 5.3 on Windows 7](http://shikii.net/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/)